# Azure Linux account management

Tags: azure, user-accounts

Is there any service in Azure for managing user accounts of the Linux VMs?

If I have multiple users that may need to SSH into a variety of Linux VMs, is there a central place to manage accounts or do I need to create and manage the users and groups on a per VM basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two options really, one is to provision a VM running whatever management solution you prefer, the other is to use Azure Active Directory Domain Services. This allows you to essentially get AD domain controllers as a service. There are a number of limitations and caveats about what you can do with AD DS, however at the core it will provide an LDAP directory to which you can join Linux VM's - see [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-admin-guide-join-rhel-linux-vm) for more details.

Comment: Thanks.  It looked like that was the best option, but just wasn't sure if I was missing something.